# How to get all of my state data just one line code with react hook?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I just try to use react hook recently.

If I extends Componet, I declare my state like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // dummy state
    this.state = {
      focus: false
      name: 'test'
      image: ''
      avatarSource: '',
      imageBase: 'sfsafsfasf',
      imageLoader: null,
    }
```

If I want to send all of the state values, I will use `...this.state`

just like:

```
sendStateFunction(...this.state);
```

If I use react hook, I declare my state like this:

```
const test = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const [sex, setSex] = useState(0); 
  const [id, setId] = useState('');
}
```

But I have no idea how to send all of the state values just use one line code:

```
sendStateFunction();  // What should I type the arguments ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React let you define state object with multiple subvalues with hooks like that :

```
function DummyComponent(){
const [state, setState] = useState({ focus: false,
    name: 'test',
    image: '',
    avatarSource: '',
    imageBase: 'sfsafsfasf',
    imageLoader: null,})
// You can update it like that:
return <Button onClick={()=>setState(prevState=>{return {...prevState, newKey:1}})}>Click</Button>
}
```

Or you can use a reducer using the hook useReducer.
All of those issues are stated in React hooks [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

Comment: Thanks. So I can use just like `...state` in your example right ?